# markdown in wordpress messes with knitr generated .md file

Tags: r, wordpress, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

Here is a concrete example:

(1) "test.Rmd" The entire test.Rmd file has a single code-chunk.

````
``` {r, tidy= TRUE}
a <- c(1,2,3); a^2
```
````

(2) `knitr` processes "test.Rmd" into ordinary markdown file "test.md". THe enitre content of the "test.md" is as follows:

````
```r
a <- c(1, 2, 3)
a^2
```

```
## [1] 1 4 9
```
````

Locally, the above results display fine in RStudio viewer and in my browser.

(3) Content of test.md is published as a post in Wordpress. Once the content is processed by Wordpress, the text-editor shows the following text. Presumably generated by wp-markdown:

```
`r
a <- c(1, 2, 3)
a^2`

\``\`

## [1] 1 4 9

\``\`
```

The above text is rendered on the published page as:

`r
a <- c(1, 2, 3)
a^2`

``\`

### [1] 1 4 9

``\`

The ## sign sign within the code-block is obviously not intended as H2. How do I prevent it from being rendered as a level-2 heading? Is this something to do with wp-markdown or conflict with some other plugin?

Apparently, triple backquotes do not work on Stackoverflow either:

```

### [1] 1 4 9

```

Thanks for Rstudio and knitr

Comment: Please fix the markup, I'm not sure what you do and don't want to be in code or header parts.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the `wp-markdown` plug-in does not support fenced code blocks, i.e. the code blocks surrounded by three backticks ```` ``` ````. You can use strict markdown syntax, i.e. indent the code blocks by four spaces. To do that, put `render_markdown(strict = TRUE)` in your R Markdown document. For example, your R code block will be rendered in the markdown output as:

```
    a <- c(1, 2, 3)
    a^2
```